# Is there a way to use the distance and catch principle with no Gi

Tags: brazilian-jiu-jitsu, mixed-martial-arts

Following this [video](https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=1laU8EeiMXA), Is there a way to use the principle with no Gi?

Comment: Would you care to paraphrase the principle in your own words? If the video link becomes invalid we'd lose the content otherwise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes! This principle is what we call kuzushi (or kusushi) in Japanese martial arts.

In Judo you use it to set up throws.  Same in Shorinji Kempo.  They use the same idea in Aikido but their terminology is usually unhelpful (and often involves the work ki).

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0ryNzeo3eoc This video shows the use of kuzushi in Judo.

In Shornji Kempo we tend to focus on being grabbed rather than grabbing.

The start of this video shows the same method being used against a wrist grab.  (We call this Gyaku-Gote named based on the way the wrist is held.  As opposed to aikido which uses a terminology largely based on foot movements)

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=72SeDjvpoVg

This video shows the same technique but from standing.  Note that the gi is not relevant here as it's a wrist and arm based technique.

When the end of the arm is being held the use of kuzushi becomes more complicated.  Note the series of 'flicking motions' before the throw.  We have separate names for each stage of breaking the balance in this way, (kuzushi being the name given to the attackers position after the first movement).

Essentially the first movement bends shoulder brings the attacker to the tips of their toes, then as they step the second 'flick' brings them flying as the lock is applied.

Here is a demonstration by an Aikido Instructor who has cross trained in Judo.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Sp-Gxzb25iA

The gi or lack thereof doesn't change the fact that being slightly further away even just for a moment is an essential tactic for grappling.  Exactly how you capitalise on this movement however, will depend on the rules of your sport or the goal of you self defence scenario.